# ApiModelProperty Annotation of objects not working with swagger

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

swagger version 1.5.20

```
 public class SomeDto extends TemporallyScopedEntityDto {

    @ApiModelProperty(value="This DOES NOT display in swagger ui docs")
    private ZonedDateTimeDto publishDate;

    @ApiModelProperty(value="This DOES display in swagger ui docs")
    private List<CodeTypeDto> territories = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Both annotations appear in the api-docs json file

However publish Date does not appear in the swagger docs UI

Territories does appear in the swagger docs UI

Is there a reason why the java object cannot be annotated like this
[image: Model]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Swagger does not really support adding description to nested fields.
See the last section of this [link](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) to get some background information about it.